# how to find the largest eigenvalue for the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the short method to find largest eigenvalue of a given matrix. If the sum of each row and coloum is same. Give answer in details with example and if some theorem is used in it, then please write it.

Comment: Did you look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem?

Comment: There is not general short method in this case.  However, there is something to be said if the entries of the matrix are all non-negative.